# Custom taxonomy - checking if name includes a declared value

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Can anyone help me adapt the below which creates a set of `<LI>` elements with custom taxonomy categories created in a custom post type I have. What I want to achieve is to only list the 'project-type' results which match a defined value.

So, I only want the `<LI>` to be listed if the 'project-type' value includes 'sector1' in the its name.

So, the 'project-type' names could be "sector1-subsector1", "sector1-subsector2", "sector2-subsector1" - from these only 2 would be listed as an `<LI>` - e.g. where the start of the name includes "sector1".

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms('project-type');
foreach ($terms as  $term) { ?>
<li data-filter=".<?php  echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></li>
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms('project-type');
foreach ($terms as  $term) { 

if(strpos($term->slug, 'sector1-') !== false){
?>
<li data-filter=".<?php  echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?>
<?php
}
?>

</li>
<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Note that unless if you're still using WordPress prior to v4.5.0, you should use `get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'project-type' ) )`, i.e. pass an array of arguments to the function. See the [`get_terms()`  documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) for more details. And your question was actually a PHP question, so you should've instead searched or asked on Stack Overflow, e.g. "how to check in PHP if a string contains a certain text, e.g. if `sector1-subsector1` contains `sector1`".